# Specify an icon in Schema in kml?

Tags: kml, google-earth, icon, schema

Is it possible to specify in a Schema an icon to be used in all the Placemarks?
Below is an example. I have replaced < and > with ~

~Schema name="SPIIA" id="SPIIA"~
~SimpleField name="Project Name" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Type" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Safeguard" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Height/Length (ft.)" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Width (ft.)" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Depth (ft.)" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Longitude" type="float"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Latitude" type="float"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Remediated?" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Last Visited" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~SimpleField name="Land Status" type="string"~~/SimpleField~
~/Schema~

~Folder~~name~SPIIA~/name~
~Placemark~
~name~21212~/name~
~ExtendedData~~SchemaData schemaUrl="#SPIIA"~
~SimpleData name="Project Name"~SPIIA~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Type"~pit~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Safeguard"~Backfill~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Height/Length (ft.)"~0~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Width (ft.)"~0~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Depth (ft.)"~0~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Longitude"~10.1234~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Latitude"~35.2345~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Remediated?"~TRUE~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Last Visited"~~/SimpleData~
~SimpleData name="Land Status"~~/SimpleData~
~/SchemaData~~/ExtendedData~
~Point~~coordinates~10.1234,35.2345~/coordinates~~/Point~
~/Placemark~
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify an icon for a Placemark, it needs to be in a Style tag, either inline in the Placemark, or as a shared Style at the top of the document and referenced by a "styleUrl" in each Placemark.